# JHipster/Angular - How to deal with removal of transition() in generator/../entity-management.component.ts.ejs (in JHipster 6.6.0)

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am starting to learn JHipster with the "Full Stack Development with JHipster (Second Edition)" book which uses JHipster 6.5.0.

In Chapter 5 "Customization and Further Development" the default table view is replaced by a list. In order to bring back the sorting functionality, the authors include the following jhiSort directive (page 134):

**jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)"**

as part of this code snippet:

```
<div class="mb-2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
  <span class="mx-2 col-1">Sort by</span>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" jhiSortBy="name">
      <span class="d-flex">
        <span jhiTranslate="storeApp.product.name">Name</span>
        &nbsp;
        <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
      </span>
    </button>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

As a result "reverse" and "transition.bind(this)" could not be resolved. I compared the "product.components.ts" file with the one from the book's source code and found out, that the "transition()" function does not exist in my file

**product.components.ts (JHipster 7.0.0.)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { IProduct } from '../product.model';

import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE } from 'app/config/pagination.constants';
import { ProductService } from '../service/product.service';
import { ProductDeleteDialogComponent } from '../delete/product-delete-dialog.component';
import { DataUtils } from 'app/core/util/data-util.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  products?: IProduct[];
  isLoading = false;
  totalItems = 0;
  itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
  page?: number;
  predicate!: string;
  ascending!: boolean;
  ngbPaginationPage = 1;

  constructor(
    protected productService: ProductService,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected dataUtils: DataUtils,
    protected router: Router,
    protected modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}

  loadPage(page?: number, dontNavigate?: boolean): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const pageToLoad: number = page ?? this.page ?? 1;

    this.productService
      .query({
        page: pageToLoad - 1,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.sort(),
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<IProduct[]>) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers, pageToLoad, !dontNavigate);
        },
        () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.onError();
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handleNavigation();
  }

  trackId(index: number, item: IProduct): number {
    return item.id!;
  }

  byteSize(base64String: string): string {
    return this.dataUtils.byteSize(base64String);
  }

  openFile(base64String: string, contentType: string | null | undefined): void {
    return this.dataUtils.openFile(base64String, contentType);
  }

  delete(product: IProduct): void {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ProductDeleteDialogComponent, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.product = product;
    // unsubscribe not needed because closed completes on modal close
    modalRef.closed.subscribe(reason => {
      if (reason === 'deleted') {
        this.loadPage();
      }
    });
  }

  protected sort(): string[] {
    const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
    if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
      result.push('id');
    }
    return result;
  }

  protected handleNavigation(): void {
    combineLatest([this.activatedRoute.data, this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap]).subscribe(([data, params]) => {
      const page = params.get('page');
      const pageNumber = page !== null ? +page : 1;
      const sort = (params.get('sort') ?? data['defaultSort']).split(',');
      const predicate = sort[0];
      const ascending = sort[1] === 'asc';
      if (pageNumber !== this.page || predicate !== this.predicate || ascending !== this.ascending) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.ascending = ascending;
        this.loadPage(pageNumber, true);
      }
    });
  }

  protected onSuccess(data: IProduct[] | null, headers: HttpHeaders, page: number, navigate: boolean): void {
    this.totalItems = Number(headers.get('X-Total-Count'));
    this.page = page;
    if (navigate) {
      this.router.navigate(['/product'], {
        queryParams: {
          page: this.page,
          size: this.itemsPerPage,
          sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc'),
        },
      });
    }
    this.products = data ?? [];
    this.ngbPaginationPage = this.page;
  }

  protected onError(): void {
    this.ngbPaginationPage = this.page ?? 1;
  }
}
```

while it exists in the author's one or in the file generated with JHipster 6.5.0.:

**product.components.ts (JHipster 6.5.0)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiDataUtils } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { IProduct } from 'app/shared/model/product.model';

import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE } from 'app/shared/constants/pagination.constants';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { ProductDeleteDialogComponent } from './product-delete-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html'
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  products: IProduct[];
  error: any;
  success: any;
  eventSubscriber: Subscription;
  routeData: any;
  links: any;
  totalItems: any;
  itemsPerPage: any;
  page: any;
  predicate: any;
  previousPage: any;
  reverse: any;

  constructor(
    protected productService: ProductService,
    protected parseLinks: JhiParseLinks,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected dataUtils: JhiDataUtils,
    protected router: Router,
    protected eventManager: JhiEventManager,
    protected modalService: NgbModal
  ) {
    this.itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.page = data.pagingParams.page;
      this.previousPage = data.pagingParams.page;
      this.reverse = data.pagingParams.ascending;
      this.predicate = data.pagingParams.predicate;
    });
  }

  loadAll() {
    this.productService
      .query({
        page: this.page - 1,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.sort()
      })
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IProduct[]>) => this.paginateProducts(res.body, res.headers));
  }

  loadPage(page: number) {
    if (page !== this.previousPage) {
      this.previousPage = page;
      this.transition();
    }
  }

  transition() {
    this.router.navigate(['/product'], {
      queryParams: {
        page: this.page,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
      }
    });
    this.loadAll();
  }

  clear() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.router.navigate([
      '/product',
      {
        page: this.page,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
      }
    ]);
    this.loadAll();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAll();
    this.registerChangeInProducts();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
  }

  trackId(index: number, item: IProduct) {
    return item.id;
  }

  byteSize(field) {
    return this.dataUtils.byteSize(field);
  }

  openFile(contentType, field) {
    return this.dataUtils.openFile(contentType, field);
  }

  registerChangeInProducts() {
    this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('productListModification', () => this.loadAll());
  }

  delete(product: IProduct) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ProductDeleteDialogComponent, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.product = product;
  }

  sort() {
    const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
    if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
      result.push('id');
    }
    return result;
  }

  protected paginateProducts(data: IProduct[], headers: HttpHeaders) {
    this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('link'));
    this.totalItems = parseInt(headers.get('X-Total-Count'), 10);
    this.products = data;
  }
}
```

To make it short:
Today, I was able to track the reason for the non-existance of the transition() function down to one of the 221 closed tickets and merged pull requests of JHipster 6.6.0:
**Fix entity pagination in Angular**
*#10959 by kaidohallik was merged on 19 Dec 2019*
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10959

Despite knowing where the changes come from, I am unable to adapt the jhiSort directive to reflect the changes.

*Can someone please tell me how to adjust the jhiSort directive so that the data is sorted correctly?*

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, the answer was quite easy as it has been part of the "product.component.html" page **before** the table view has been replaced by a list view.

The HTML tr tag featured the following **jhiSort directive**

```
<tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="ascending" [callback]="loadPage.bind(this)">
```

As you can see, all that has to be done is using "ascending" instead of "reverse" and "loadPage" instead of "transition".

With these two changes the sorting works fine.