# How to sort table in jhipster? Not sure how it works

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sorting, jhipster

I've been learning jhipster for the past week now and I'm trying to implement a sortable table. I wanna ask how does the `jhiSort` and `jhiSortBy` work? I don't quite understand what does the `predicate`, `ascending` and `callback function` in `jhiSort` do. Also, which files do the `id`, `date` and `amount` in `jhiSortBy` come from and how does `jhiSortBy` work?

```
<tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)">
        <th jhiSortBy="id"><span>ID</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
        <th jhiSortBy="date"><span>Date</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
        <th jhiSortBy="amount"><span>Amount</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>

</tr>
```

Comment: If you are using **JHipster 6.6.0 or later**, **ascending** and **callback** need different settings. `<tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="ascending" [callback]="loadPage.bind(this)">`. See <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911687/jhipster-angular-how-to-deal-with-removal-of-transition-in-generator-enti>

Answer (score 2):

[jhiSort](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/main/src/directive/sort.directive.ts) and [jhiSortBy](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/main/src/directive/sort-by.directive.ts) are two directives provided by JHipster that help you implement sorting in data tables. You can see exactly what they do in the links I've provided.

### jhiSortBy

The call you see in the header of each column just tells the `jhiSortBy` directive the name of the attribute it will sort the table by. In your case this means `id`, `date` and `amount` are all attributes of the entities being listed in your table.

This directive handles the user interaction and calls `jhiSort` to do the actual sorting, plus some extra steps to manage icon changes.

### jhiSort

This directive has three properties:

```
    @Input() predicate: string;
    @Input() ascending: boolean;
    @Input() callback: Function;
```

When you do `[(predicate)]="predicate"` you are telling angular that the `predicate` property of the `jhiSort` directive (left hand side of the assignment) will bind to a property in your component of the same name (right hand side). So in your `*.component.ts` you must have a property named `predicate` that will store the sorting information.

The directive has also a boolean property named `ascending`, when you do `[(ascending)]="reverse"` you are telling angular to bind the `ascending` directive property to a component property named `reverse`, just like before but this time the names don't match. This property controls only the sorting direction (ascending or descending).

Finally, `callback` is just the method that will be called on user interaction (click on a table header) to put everything in motion. `transition` is the name of such method in your `*.component.ts`, and it looks something like this:

```js
  transition(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['./'], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent,
      queryParams: {
        page: this.page,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc'),
      },
    });
  }
```

This will force a navigation change so that the new order and page information persist on the URL, allowing future navigation events to get back without resetting the table.

This navigation change eventually calls `loadAll()` sending a query to your server-side with the new ordering (and paging) parameters.

The result of this query (a properly ordered list of entities) will be later sent back to the client-side to be displayed.

Very roughly this is how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I is not working correctly:
I found the solution,
it is related to the method
fillComponentAttributesFromResponseBody

```html
change the content of that method to be like this::
  protected fillComponentAttributesFromResponseBody(data: IReferences[] | null): IReferences[] {
    const referencesNew = [];
    if (data) {
      for (const d of data) {
        if (referencesNew.map(op => op.id).indexOf(d.id) === -1) {
          referencesNew.push(d);
        }
      }
    }
    return referencesNew;
  }
```

and it will work.
enjoy